# Bootstrap pills sub menu not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a project with bootstrap. I just included a sub menu in the pills `navbar` but it doesn't work. When I click on messages nothing happens

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
<li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li class="dropdown" role="presentation">
<a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">About</a>

<ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Inbox</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Drafts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sent Items</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Trash</a></li>
</ul>

</li>
<li role="presentation"><a href="#">Users</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Any help with the script above. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

See how `data-toggle="dropdown"` is in the anchor tag for About? It appears that you have the dropdown menu under About, not Messages.

Also, be sure to include the Bootstrap JavaScript. There should be a tag like `<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>` in the `<head>` section of your HTML. This is what enables the dropdown to work.